# Saving URLs to the bookmarks ,chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is popup.js:

```
function GetUrls()
{
var CurrentTabs = new Array();
chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    {
        CurrentTabs[i] = tabs[i];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < CurrentTabs.length; i++) 
    {
document.write("<b>" + CurrentTabs[i].title + "<button " +"</b>" + "<br/><a href='" + CurrentTabs[i].url + "' target='_blank'>" + CurrentTabs[i].url + "</a><br/><br/>");
   }
});
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", GetUrls());

function Save(){
    var title = document.title;
    var url = document.location.href;
 chrome.bookmarks.create({'parentId': bookmarkBar.id,
                         'document.title': 'Extension bookmarks'},
                        function(newFolder) {
  alert("added folder: " + newFolder.title);
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",Save());
```

I tey this idea to save URLs to bookmarks,but nothing happen.
Any idea please about how can i do that?

Comment: I am almost sure that your problem is in "bookmarkBar.id". Do you see an error saying "cannot find id of undefined" or something similar? My understanding is that you will need to find out the id of your intended parent folder by traversing the bookmarks tree. I can write a working code when I have time and post it here if your issue is not solved by then.

Comment: First error should be obvious. You do not have any function named findOrCreateDestinationFolder. For second error, you are not supposed to add event handlers in HTML. If you are attaching click event handlers in HTML, it will not work. Use addEventListener() function instead.

Comment: @zambrey no i don't attach click event handlers in HTML
This is popup.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Links Collector</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<style>
body {
width:500px;
height: 300px;
}
</style>
</body>

</html>

Comment: Are you completely new to programming? You were in fact adding onclick events in HTML for button in document.write. I am updating the code in the answer. It's exactly what you want and it works fine. No one can help you more than this now.

Comment: @zambrey Yes,Iam new at javascript,html and this is my first extension.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code to save bookmarks. When the popup is opened, the code starts by searching for a folder titled 'Extension Bookmarks' in bookmarks tree. If found, it is saved as `destFolder` for future use and if not, a new folder with that title is created under Bookmarks bar and set as `destFolder`.
When the button is clicked, a Google bookmark is added to 'Extension Bookmarks'.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Bookmarks Sample",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Description",

    "browser_action": 
    {
       "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "bookmarks",
        "tabs"
     ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </footer>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function GetUrls()
{
chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    {
        document.write("<a href='" + tabs[i].url + "' target='_blank'>" + "<b>" + tabs[i].title + "</b>" + "</a></br><button style=\"width:100%;height:30px;\" data-title=\""+tabs[i].title+"\" data-url=\""+tabs[i].url+"\">Bookmark above link</button>");
    }
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++)
    {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click',function(){addBookmark(this.getAttribute("data-url"), this.getAttribute("data-title"));})
    }
});
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", GetUrls());

var destFolder, bookmarkBar, finalMessage="";

chrome.bookmarks.getTree(findOrCreateDestinationFolder);

function findOrCreateDestinationFolder(rootNodes)
{
    var rootNode;
    if(rootNodes.length>0)
    {
        rootNode = rootNodes[0];
    }
    destFolder = findBookmarksFolder(rootNode, "Extension Bookmarks");
    if(!destFolder)
    {
        bookmarkBar = findBookmarksFolder(rootNode,"Bookmarks bar");
        chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId:bookmarkBar?bookmarkBar.id:"1",title:"Extension Bookmarks"}, function(bmk){
            destFolder=bmk;
            finalMessage += "Destination Folder created under Bookmarks bar.\n"
        });
    }
    else
    {
        finalMessage += "Destination Folder exists.\n"
    }
}

function findBookmarksFolder(rootNode, searchString)
{
    if(rootNode.url)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if(rootNode.title.indexOf(searchString)>=0)
    {
        return rootNode;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<rootNode.children.length; i++)
    {
        var dest = findBookmarksFolder(rootNode.children[i], searchString);
        if(dest)
        {
            return dest;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function addBookmark(bookmarkURL, bookmarktitle)
{
    if(destFolder)
    {
        chrome.bookmarks.create({title:bookmarktitle,parentId:destFolder.id,url:bookmarkURL});
        finalMessage += "Added bookmark.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        finalMessage += "Could not add bookmark.\n";
    }
    alert(finalMessage);
}
```

Comment: This extension makes Google Chrome not responding, by the way this is different idea from that I want in my extension,It saves only one URL"Google".
My extension collects current URLs and I want to choose any URL of them to save to the bookmarks.How can I use these functions in the "Bookmarks Sample" in my"popup.js" to make what I want? 
Thanks

Comment: It's a sample code. I hoped you would be able to manipulate it to fit to your needs. 
I am not sure about 'not responding' part, it worked fine on my system. But this is THE way you need to use to save bookmarks to a folder you want.

Comment: I tried once again, seems to work alright. Try to use the approach and not the exact code. Comment here if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: ok,I'll try to manipulate it and tell you what I made..
this is the error of code in the question:
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

Comment: I try to use this sample extension to solve my problem ,but nothing happen.Do you have any idea or hints?

Comment: It's difficult to deduce without taking a look at the code. But if I were you, I would look if the parent id is as expected/if I have bookmarks permission in manifest /if there are any javascript errors. If you add your updated code in your question, that will help.